# Angular tests don't detect changes in input's value

Tags: angular

I have an app where I change the value of an `input` and it should immediately change the value of an `h1`. It works well when tested manually (changing the `input` changes the `h1`), but it's not working from a test (changing the `input` has no effect on the content of the `h1`).

I've double checked I'm invoking `detectChanges` and `whenStable` when *I think* I should, but still I've got no luck.

Can someone spot what I'm doing wrong?

## app.component.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <form>
      <input type="text" name="query-input" [(ngModel)]="myText" />
    </form>
    <h1>H1 content is "{{myText}}"</h1>
  `
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  public myText = 'Default value';

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.myText = 'Value from ngOnInit';
  }
}
```

## app.component.spec.ts

```js
import { TestBed, async } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

describe('AppComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        FormsModule
      ],
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  it('should work', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    console.log(fixture.componentInstance.myText); // VALUE IS OK: "Default value"
    fixture.detectChanges();
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      console.log(fixture.componentInstance.myText); // VALUE IS OK: "Value from ngOnInit"
      const compiled = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
      compiled.querySelector('input').value = 'Value from test';
      fixture.detectChanges();
      fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
        console.log(compiled.querySelector('input').value); // VALUE IS OK: 'Value from test'
        console.log(fixture.componentInstance.myText); // VALUE IS UNEXPECTED: 'Value from ngOnInit'
        console.log(compiled.querySelector('h1').textContent); // VALUE IS UNEXPECTED: 'H1 content is "Value from ngOnInit"'
      });
    });
  });
});
```

So in those 2 last `console.log` I'm getting `Value from ngOnInit` but I expected to get `Value from test`

Angular version used: 7.2.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the issue, it's not enough to change the `value` of the `input`, one needs to invoke `dispatchEvent` afterwards.

So this code:

```js
  ...
  compiled.querySelector('input').value = 'Value from test';
  fixture.detectChanges();
  ...
```

Needed to be changed to:

```js
  ...
  compiled.querySelector('input').value = 'Value from test';
  compiled.querySelector('input').dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
  fixture.detectChanges();
  ...
```

#### Note:

If the previous solution doesn't work for you, try sending the `blur` event after the `input`. I hit one case in which `input` was not enough.